# How to convert GeoPoint in Firestore to LatLng

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geopoints

Hi I'm using Android Studio and I'm having trouble of converting data that I've got from Firestore. I saved data in my Firestore type GeoPoint and I want to query it and convert to Object type `LatLng`.

Here is my code:

```
    final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    final CollectionReference stores = db.collection("stores");
    stores.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.i(TAG,document.getData().get("position").toString());
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

and Here is what i got

```
    12-16 10:59:21.557 28239-28239/com.company.yummy.yummy I/firebaseCatch: GeoPoint { latitude=29.339555, longitude=169.715858 }
    12-16 10:59:21.557 28239-28239/com.company.yummy.yummy I/firebaseCatch: GeoPoint { latitude=68.085393, longitude=-42.081575 }
    12-16 10:59:21.557 28239-28239/com.company.yummy.yummy I/firebaseCatch: GeoPoint { latitude=16.503923, longitude=90.196118 }
    12-16 10:59:21.557 28239-28239/com.company.yummy.yummy I/firebaseCatch: GeoPoint { latitude=-69.424524, longitude=-71.356333 }
    12-16 10:59:21.557 28239-28239/com.company.yummy.yummy I/firebaseCatch: GeoPoint { latitude=69.502257, longitude=71.100474 }
```

All i need is to get latitude,longtitude value to set into LatLng object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To solve this, you can simply use `getGeoPoint()` method like this:

```
GeoPoint geoPoint = document.getGeoPoint("position");
```

And then use:

```
double lat = geoPoint.getLatitude();
double lng = geoPoint.getLongitude();
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
```

Comment: how if in nested object?. Products products = documentSnapshot.toObject(Products.class);  System.out.println(products.getLocation().get("geoPoint").toString());

Comment: @LatiefAnwar In that case you should simply use: `System.out.println(products.getLocation().toString());` which will return a Geopoint objct. If you have hard time solving that, please post another fresh question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: can't we simplify it more by 

LatLng latLng = new LatLng(document.getGeoPoint("position").getLatitude(),  document.getGeoPoint("position").getLongitude());

Comment: @IzhanAli You can do it if you want.

Answer (score 5):

This has worked for me with flutter cloud_firestore

```
void getData() {
databaseReference
    .collection("stores")
    .getDocuments()
    .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  snapshot.documents.forEach((f) {
    print('${f.data}}');
    GeoPoint pos = f.data['position'];
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(pos.latitude, pos.longitude);

  });
});
}
```

Reference - https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-realtime-geolocation-firebase/

Answer (score 3):

You need to extract the Latitude and Longitude from the Geopoint object received,

and make a new LatLng object, like so

```
double lat = document.getData().get("position").getLatitude();
double lng = document.getData().get("position").getLongitude ();
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
```

Comment: How to extract the Latitude and Longitude from the Geopoint I'm sorry I'm a beginner of android studio Thank you very much

Comment: @SupagonSrisawas check the docs https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/GeoPoint